# 0..1 cardinality of same model

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have a task model and would like that every task could have 0 or 1 top task:

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TopTaskId { get; set; }
    public virtual Task TopTask { get; set; }
}
```

Is this okay so far?

How would my OnModelCreating method look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need one. You do need to make TopTaskId `int?` if you want to have 0 or 1 relationship (FK is nullable in the db).